# AWS: unable to find credentials error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have ASP.NET Core 2 application. I have configured AWS in appsettings.json

like below

```
"AWS": {
    "Profile": "default",
    "ProfilesLocation": "D:\\_profiles\\awsprofile"
  }
```

i made sure i have the `awsprofile` file available at that location with below information

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Then im trying to create instance of S3Client like below

```
    var regionEndPoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-west-1");                                
    var client = new AmazonS3Client(regionEndPoint));
```

However, i am getting exception `Unable to find the 'default' profile in CredentialProfileStoreChain.`

> Application startup exception: Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException:
>   Unable to find credentials
>
> Exception 1 of 3: Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: Unable to find
>   the 'default' profile in CredentialProfileStoreChain.    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetAWSCredentials(ICredentialProfileSource
>   source)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous)
>
> Exception 2 of 3: System.InvalidOperationException: The environment
>   variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY/AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
>   were not set with AWS credentials.    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials()
>   at Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials..ctor()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.<>c.b__9_1()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous)
>
> Exception 3 of 3: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response
>   status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__27.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass1_1`1.<<RunSync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.ExclusiveSynchronizationContext.BeginMessageLoop()
>   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task)
>   at Amazon.Util.AWSSDKUtils.DownloadStringContent(Uri uri, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.URIBasedRefreshingCredentialHelper.GetContents(Uri uri)
>   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.InstanceProfileAWSCredentials.d__10.MoveNext()
>   at Amazon.Runtime.InstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetFirstRole()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.ECSEC2CredentialsWrapper()
>   at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous)
>
> at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous)    at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.cs:line 30    at
>   Api.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in
>   D:\Jenkins\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\Src\Api\Startup.cs:line 75
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>   crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
>         Application startup exception Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to find credentials
>
> Exception 1 of 3: Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: Unable to find
>   the 'default' profile in CredentialProfileStoreChain.    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetAWSCredentials(ICredentialProfileSource
>   source)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous)
>
> Exception 2 of 3: System.InvalidOperationException: The environment
>   variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY/AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
>   were not set with AWS credentials.    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials()
>   at Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials..ctor()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.<>c.b__9_1()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous)
>
> Exception 3 of 3: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response
>   status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__27.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass1_1`1.<<RunSync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.ExclusiveSynchronizationContext.BeginMessageLoop()
>   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task)
>   at Amazon.Util.AWSSDKUtils.DownloadStringContent(Uri uri, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.URIBasedRefreshingCredentialHelper.GetContents(Uri uri)
>   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.InstanceProfileAWSCredentials.d__10.MoveNext()
>   at Amazon.Runtime.InstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetFirstRole()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.ECSEC2CredentialsWrapper()
>   at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous)
>
> at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous)    at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:line 30    at
>   Api.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in
>   D:\Jenkins\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\Startup.cs:line 75
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>
> Unhandled Exception: Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to
>   find credentials
>
> Exception 1 of 3: Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: Unable to find
>   the 'default' profile in CredentialProfileStoreChain.    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetAWSCredentials(ICredentialProfileSource
>   source)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous)
>
> Exception 2 of 3: System.InvalidOperationException: The environment
>   variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY/AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
>   were not set with AWS credentials.    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials()
>   at Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials..ctor()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.<>c.b__9_1()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous)
>
> Exception 3 of 3: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response
>   status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__27.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass1_1`1.<<RunSync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.ExclusiveSynchronizationContext.BeginMessageLoop()
>   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task)
>   at Amazon.Util.AWSSDKUtils.DownloadStringContent(Uri uri, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.URIBasedRefreshingCredentialHelper.GetContents(Uri uri)
>   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.InstanceProfileAWSCredentials.d__10.MoveNext()
>   at Amazon.Runtime.InstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetFirstRole()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.ECSEC2CredentialsWrapper()
>   at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous)
>
> at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous)    at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:line 30    at
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\Src\Api\Startup.cs:line 75
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()    at
>   Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   D:\Jenkins\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\Src\Api\Program.cs:line 20

Answer (score 1):

Your appsettings and credential file look good. However, I don't believe calling the constructor that way will automatically find the credentials. You can use the AWS .NET Core setup package to handle this for you. It's quite easy to follow [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html) to get the IAmazonS3 via dependency injection.

In a nutshell:

If you're using ASP.NET Core, add the package `AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup` from nuget.

The add the AWS config and service in ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    ....

    // This will find "AWS" section in your app settings
    services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());

    // This is used to find your credentials and give you the dependency
    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
}
```

Then you can access the IAmazonS3 instance in your controller, class etc by dependency injection:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    IAmazonS3 S3Client { get; set; }

    public HomeController(IAmazonS3 s3Client)
    {
        this.S3Client = s3Client;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Correct, in .NET Core we don't have ConfigurationManager available to us in the SDK to find this configuration information. Which is why `AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup` was created.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use `AmazonS3Client` to download a file given s3 url. A File can be situated in any of the 4 US regions `us-west-1`, `us-west-2`,`us-east-1` and `us-east-2`
When you create a instance of `AmazonS3Client` using the flowing code, then s3 client can download a file only from the configured region in appsettings.json

```
// This will find "AWS" section in your app settings
services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());

// This is used to find your credentials and give you the dependency
services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
```

So, instead i created a Factory that creates the instances of `AmazonS3Client` and then use the appropriate S3 Client based on the region.

```
public class S3ClientFactory : IS3ClientFactory
{        
    private IDictionary<string, IAmazonS3> _container = null;

    private S3ClientFactory()
    {
        _container = new Dictionary<string, IAmazonS3>();
    }

    public static IS3ClientFactory Create(string[] regions, AWSOptions options)
    {
        var factory = new S3ClientFactory();
        foreach (var region in regions)
        {
            var regionEndPoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region);
            options.Region = regionEndPoint;
            factory._container.Add(region, options.CreateServiceClient<IAmazonS3>());
        }

        return factory;
    }

    public IAmazonS3 GetS3Client(string region)
    {
        if (!_container.ContainsKey(region))
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not find s3 client for key {0}", region));
        }
        return _container[region];
    }
}
```

and the in Startup.cs register it

```
var awsOptions = Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
var regions = new string[] { "us-west-1", "us-west-2", "us-east-1", "us-east-2" }; // add supported regions as needed
services.AddSingleton<IS3ClientFactory>(S3ClientFactory.Create(regions,awsOptions));
```

i then parse the incoming s3 url using `Amazon.S3.Util.AmazonS3Uri` to get region and use factory to get correct S3Client

```
   var s3Uri = new AmazonS3Uri(sourceS3Uri);
   var s3Client = _factory.GetS3Client(s3Uri.Region.SystemName);
```